# Upload files to s3 bucket using AWS console having policy with deny condition to match "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I am trying to upload files to S3 bucket having default encryption enabled as SSE-KMS and a deny statement to bucket policy using AWS console however, I am getting access denied error. If I remove the deny condition from bucket policy, I am  able to upload files to S3 using AWS console.

I understand that this can be achieved using aws cli by passing `--sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id <kms-key-id>` however, I would like to know is there a way to upload files through **AWS console**?

Bucket policy -->

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "KMSPut",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        }
]
}
```

KMS Policy -->

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-default-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/MyRole",
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM Role Policy -->

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:12345678:key/1234-abcd-dcba-4321"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The (new) S3 Console upload feature includes options to select KMS and a KMS key. Expand the relevant section in the UI under 'Additional upload options'.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did try that few minutes ago and able to upload the files using KMS key. Thanks for this.